# Vuejs app showing error in build without changes

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

Good morning, today after one successfully build in one hotfix, a second build show a error in

```
TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function
```

After many changes, this persist and i try run build in another apps with config relative same, all aps in vuejs show the same error above, can help-me?

```
ERROR  TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function
TypeError: ErrorStackParser.parse is not a function
at getOriginalErrorStack (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/extractWebpackError.js:31:29)
at extractError (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/extractWebpackError.js:22:20)
at Array.map ()
at processErrors (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/core/transformErrors.js:31:17)
at FriendlyErrorsWebpackPlugin.displayErrors (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/friendly-errors-plugin.js:97:29)
at doneFn (node_modules/@soda/friendly-errors-webpack-plugin/src/friendly-errors-plugin.js:57:14)
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :18:1)
at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
at node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:304:22
at Compiler.emitRecords (node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:499:39)
at node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:298:10
at node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:485:14
at _next0 (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :16:1)
at eval (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :24:1)
at node_modules/copy-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:115:7
at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), :20:1)
```

Comment: is ErrorStackParser undefined?

Comment: Keep an eye on this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/7180

Comment: Related to the comment above, here is a fix: https://github.com/stacktracejs/error-stack-parser/issues/80#issuecomment-1147670164

`"resolutions": {
"error-stack-parser": "2.0.6"
}`

Looks like there was a problem with a new version of error-stack-parser.